Insulating a pre-existing suspended bathroom ceiling
The previous owner of my house has redone the bathrooms and toilets pretty well, with nicely finished suspended ceilings and downlights.
What he didn’t take care of properly was insulation. The space between the suspended ceiling and the real ceiling is not well-insulated from the roof, which means in winter there is strong draft and even wind in that area, making toilets and bathroom some of the coldest rooms in the house.
I have found a way to block the major air inlets into the roof and ceiling spaces, which will kill the wind issue. But for the draft to stop completely I need to insulate above the suspended ceiling somehow without tearing it apart, because it remains connected to the poorly insulated roof space (see pic below)

I was thinking of blowing in some styrofoam beads through the downlight holes, and then seal those holes off when reinstalling the lights. The risk is that styrofoam will react with the plastic cable shields (e.g., for lights, fan, etc.) and create short-circuit/fire hazard.
Now my questions:

Is there any better way to insulate this space apart from styrofoam beads, short of completely tearing out the ceiling?
Are there any other risk associated with styrofoam beads used for this purpose?
How can I protect the in-ceiling cables in order to mitigate the reaction risk?

P.S.: Note that toilets and bathrooms are otherwise efficiently ventilated and heated with automatic humidity and temperature-based activation.

Some pics would help here.  Is there no insulation above the "real ceiling?"  What exactly are we talking about here?  Is there an attic?  What are you calling a "crawl space?"

Good idea. I added a schematic drawing.

That helps.  Do you know why there is a suspended ceiling?  And is the "loft" area habitable, or is it just insulation laying on top of the bath's "real ceiling?"

I have no idea why there is a suspended ceiling. The only purpose of it seems to be  holding the flush downlights. The loft is actually the master bedroom. There is only a thin layer of insulation under the suspended laminate flooring, then 10-15cm of space, then the “real” ceiling / floor (wooden). So, my drawing is a bit inaccurate there, with regard to the flooring.

"Suspended laminate flooring" = "floating laminate flooring?"  Looks to me like you simply need to seal the breach between the eave and bath.
